# JPA Query with several different @Id columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

## Problem

To make my code cleaner i want to introduce a generic Repository that each Repository could extend and therefore reduce the code i have to have in each of them. The problem is, that the Ids differ from Class to Class. On one (see example below) it would be `id` and in the other `randomNumber` and on the other may even be an @EmbeddedId. I want to have a derived (or non derived) query in the respository that gets One by id.

### Preferred solution

I Imagine having something like:

```java
public interface IUniversalRepository<T, K>{
    @Query("select t from # {#entityName} where @id = ?1")
    public T findById(K id);
}
```

## Ecample Code

##### (that does not work because attribute `id` cannot be found on Settings)

```java
public interface IUniversalRepository<T, K>{
    //should return the object with the id, reagardless of the column name
    public T findById(K id);
}
```

```java
// two example classes with different @Id fields
public class TaxRate {

    @Id
    @Column()
    private Integer id;

    ...
}

public class Settings{

    @Id
    @Column() //cannot rename this column because it has to be named exactly as it is for backup reason
    private String randomNumber;

    ...
}
```

```java
// the Repository would be used like this
public interface TaxRateRepository extends IUniversalRepository<TaxRate, Integer> {
}

public interface SettingsRepository extends IUniversalRepository<TaxRate, String> {
}
```

Happy for suggestions.

Comment: The universal repository already exists in JPA: `javax.persistence.EntityManager#find(java.lang.Class<T>, java.lang.Object)`

Comment: This would still require a Class where i have the entityManager and i can also not create Queries (like findByIdAndName) with other fields, right?

Comment: what's the problem using ```extends JpaRepository<Entity, IdType>'

Comment: This actually solves a portion of the Problem, thats true. Nevertheless i cannot produce queries with other fields. like findByIdAndType(K id, String type). if the jparepository can build such queries, why cant I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of retrieving JPA entities via "id query" is not so good as you might think, the main problem is that is much slower, especially when you are hitting the same entity within transaction multiple times: if flush mode is set to AUTO (which is actually the reasonable default) Hibernate needs to perform dirty checking and flush changes into database before executing JPQL query, moreover, Hibernate doesn't guarantee that entities, retrieved via "id query" are not actually stale - if entity was already present in persistence context Hibernate basically ignores DB data.

The best way to retrieve entities by id is to call `EntityManager#find(java.lang.Class<T>, java.lang.Object)` method, which in turn backs up `CrudRepository#findById` method, so, yours `findByIdAndType(K id, String type)` should actually look like:

```
default Optional<T> findByIdAndType(K id, String type) {
    return findById(id)
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getType(), type));
}
```

However, the desire to place some kind of `id` placeholder in JQPL query is not so bad - one of it's applications could be preserving order stability in queries with pagination. I would suggest you to file corresponding CR to `spring-data` project.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. Your implementation of "findByIdAndType" is a nice solution. first i was afraid of the impact of the findById but i forgot that findById literally should return a single object. I didn't get some of your hibernate deep-dive but thats ok, i'm not that deep into the matter.