# Build single object for save with JPA instead of multiple saves and updates

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot rest API where I use JPA to write the request & response messages for several dependency applications to a Postgresql database:

Entities are structured as follows:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "quote_master")
@Getter
@Setter
public class QuoteMaster {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(
          name = "quote_master_sequence",
          sequenceName = "quote_master_sequence")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "quote_master_sequence")
  @Column(name = "quote_master_id")
  private Long quoteMasterId;

  @Column(name = "quote_reference")
  private String quoteReference;

  @Column(name = "transaction_id")
  private String transactionId;

  @Column(name = "quote_status")
  private String quoteStatus;

  @Column(name = "quote_type")
  private String quoteType;

  @Column(name = "payment_type")
  private String paymentType;

  @Column(name = "transaction_timestamp")
  @CreationTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime transactionTimestamp;

  @Column(name = "client_source")
  private String clientSource;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quoteMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<DependencyMessage> dependencyMessages;

  public void addDependencyMessage(DependencyMessage theDependencyMessage) {
    if (dependencyMessages == null) {
      dependencyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    dependencyMessages.add(theDependencyMessage);
    theDependencyMessage.setQuoteMaster(this);
  }

}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@Table(name = "dependency_messages")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DependencyMessage {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "call_type")
  private RequestOrResponse requestOrResponse;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "message_type")
  private MessageType messageType;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "service")
  private DependencyApplication dependencyApplication;

  @Column(name = "class_name")
  private String className;

  @Column(name = "date_created")
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Date dateCreated;
  @Column(name = "message", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
  private String message;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "quote_master_id")
  private QuoteMaster quoteMAster;
}
```

In my quote service, where the first message is found, I have this:

```
DependencyMessage dependencyMessage =
    DependencyMessage.builder()
        .requestOrResponse(RequestOrResponse.REQUEST)
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
        .dependencyApplication(DependencyApplication.APP1)
        .className("QuoteService")
        .message(quoteRequest.toString())
        .build();
    QuoteMaster quoteMaster =
        QuoteMaster.builder()
            .quoteReference(quoteRequest.getQuoteReference())
            .transactionId(quoteRequest.getTransactionId())
            .clientSource(quoteRequest.getSourceSystems().getOrigin().sourceSystem)
            .build();
    quoteMaster.addDependencyMessage(dependencyMessage);

    quoteMasterRepository.save(quoteMaster);
      Long quoteMasterId = quoteMaster.getQuoteMasterId();
```

`quoteMasterId` is then passed to any subsequent methods that send or receive a message where it is used to look up the relevant quote and do any update:

```
DependencyMessage dependencyMessage =
    DependencyMessage.builder()
        .requestOrResponse(RequestOrResponse.REQUEST)
        .messageType(MessageType.XML)
        .dependencyApplication(DependencyApplication.APP2)
        .className("RatingService")
        .message(requestXML)
        .build();
QuoteMaster quoteMaster = quoteMasterRepository.findByQuoteMasterId(quoteMaster);
quoteMaster.addDependencyMessage(dependencyMessage);
quoteMasterRepository.save(quoteMaster);
```

The result of this is a lot of `findByQuoteMasterId()` and `save()` interactions with the database. I'm worried about a performance hit so was wondering is there a way to build some sort of global object on which I could do just one save at the end of the process?

Comment: Is there any reason using `quoteMasterRepository.findByQuoteMasterId` instead of built-in `quoteMasterRepository.findById`? please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884096/3426309

Comment: I updated that to use `findById()`: `QuoteMaster quoteMaster = quoteMasterRepository.findByQuoteMasterId(quoteMaster).get();`