# Why is Hibernate 6.2 translating JPQL equals operator into IN operator?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.1 / Hibernate 6.2 application that connects to an Oracle 12c database using the following driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This application has the following repository interface and classes:

```
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends Repository<SomeEntity, SomeEntityId> {
  @Query("""
      FROM SomeEntity
      WHERE id = :id
        AND description is not null
      """)
  Optional<SomeEntity> find(SomeEntityId id);
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class SomeEntityId {
    private Long idX;
    private Long idY;
    private Long idZ;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeEntityId id;
    private String description;
}
```

When the `find` query gets executed, Hibernate 6.2 translates the JPQL into the following SQL:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        s1_0.idx,
        s1_0.idy,
        s1_0.idz,
        s1_0.description 
    from
        some_entity s1_0 
    where
        (
            s1_0.idx,s1_0.idy,s1_0.idz
        ) in (select
            ?,?,? 
        from
            dual) 
        and s1_0.description is not null
```

I was wondering why is Hibernate 6.2 translating the `id = :id` into a sub query, and not just comparing the composite primary key field by field, like Hibernate 5 did?

I tried to execute the same code in Spring Boot 2.7.13 / Hibernate 5.6, and the JPQL was translated as expected:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        someentity0_.idx as idx1_1_,
        someentity0_.idy as idy2_1_,
        someentity0_.idz as idz3_1_,
        someentity0_.description as description4_1_ 
    from
        some_entity someentity0_ 
    where
        someentity0_.idx=? 
        and someentity0_.idy=? 
        and someentity0_.idz=? 
        and (
            someentity0_.description is not null
        )
```

The composite PK attributes were compared individually using `AND` and `=`, as opposed to Hibernate 6.2, that compared using the `IN` operator:

```
...
        (
            s1_0.idx,s1_0.idy,s1_0.idz
        ) in (select
            ?,?,? 
        from
            dual) 
...
```

Comment: First thing I'd check is the speed or plan of both queries; maybe for this flavor this is better by some metric?

Comment: Hey, @DaveNewton! In fact, the Oracle execution plan for the query translated by Hibernate 6.2 shows some extra steps if compared to Hibernate 5.6, and also the cost is higher, even though both cost values are relatively low (9 and 6, respectively).

Comment: :shrug: Don't know then *(well, didn't know before, either)*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you most probably do not need to use `@Query`-annotated methods when retrieving entities by id, please check some thoughts on that here: [JPA Query with several different @Id columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884096/3426309)

The behaviour you described was introduced in HBN6 and the relevant code is located in [AbstractSqlAstTranslator#visitRelationalPredicate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/c5c3bb8ac8ae3ec657126d0ac01b55f416a8ff99/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/sql/ast/spi/AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java#L7527) method:

```java
else if ( needsTupleComparisonEmulation( operator ) ) {
    rhsTuple = SqlTupleContainer.getSqlTuple( rhsExpression );
    assert rhsTuple != null;
    // Some DBs like Oracle support tuples only for the IN subquery predicate
    if ( ( operator == ComparisonOperator.EQUAL || operator == ComparisonOperator.NOT_EQUAL ) && supportsRowValueConstructorSyntaxInInSubQuery() ) {
        comparisonPredicate.getLeftHandExpression().accept( this );
        if ( operator == ComparisonOperator.NOT_EQUAL ) {
            appendSql( " not" );
        }
        appendSql( " in (" );
        renderExpressionsAsSubquery( rhsTuple.getExpressions() );
        appendSql( CLOSE_PARENTHESIS );
    }
    else {
        emulateTupleComparison(
                lhsTuple.getExpressions(),
                rhsTuple.getExpressions(),
                operator,
                true
        );
    }
}
```

In this particular case, I would say HBN developers are not familiar with `Oracle` syntax, i.e. comment `Oracle support tuples only for the IN subquery predicate` in aforementioned code snippet is not correct: the standard `Oracle` way to write expressions comparing tuples is following (note double parenthesis):

```sql
(s1_0.idx,s1_0.idy,s1_0.idz) IN ((?,?,?))
```

If you are experiencing performance issues I would recommend to raise a bug in [HBN Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/)